# Inserting a pair into the map and constness?

Tags: c++, containers

Is there any valid reason why would one prefer one pair over the other over the third over the fourth in the following sample?

```
map<const int, int> test;

test.insert(const pair<const int, int>(3, 9));
test.insert(const pair<int, int>(3, 9));
test.insert(pair<int, int>(3, 9));
test.insert(pair<const int, int>(5, 9));
```

Comment: What means prefer? You cant insert first 2 pairs btw

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't even check the first two... however, there isn't any difference between last two pair insetions? hope this isn't stupid question.

Comment: @DenisErmolin I'm wondering whether the first two are legal.  If they are, there should be no problem inserting them; the compiler actually inserts a copy, and top level const doesn't play a role.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You have to typedef it, it is not (syntactically) valid.

Comment: @jpalecek That's what I thought, but I also thought that people would only post code which compiled:-).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Same here, I just looked into the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes. A dumb compiler will invoke one extra conversion constructor in this code

```
test.insert(pair<const int, int>(5, 9));
```

but an optimizing compiler will make it the same as other alternatives.

I only ask, who would want to write code like this? Normally, I would write `test.insert(std::make_pair(3, 9))` and wouldn't care.

Comment: Alternatively, I usually have a typedef for the map, and write `MapType::value_type( key, value )`.

Answer (score 0):

Last 2 pairs has no difference when inserting into map. Keys in map are const by default, just use make_pair function